# Why are some aircraft built in a single country, whereas others are a collaboration of many countries?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-manufacturer

The USA has developed numerous aircraft; Sweden developed the [JAS Gripen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saab_JAS_39_Gripen) and France developed the [Rafale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_Rafale), by themselves.

But most of the modern aircraft developed by the UK and Germany needed collaborations. Yet both of them have the technology and enough money to build aircraft on their own. Why did the [Eurofighter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurofighter_Typhoon) need collaboration among four countries?

On the other hand being a collaborative effort, the F-35 became one of the most problematic projects in aircraft history. So why collaborate?

Comment: This question has more to do with politics than with aviation

Comment: This question contains a few somewhat hidden assumptions, for instance that Eurofighter "needs" the collaboration, or that Sweden developed the Gripen all by themselves.

Comment: Without the collaboration, the Eurofighter would had become a better product. Just two things: Its high alfa pitch-up and (relatively) high RCS - both could have been avoided easily during the design phase. Also the small wing area: Its 50 m² were decided by Maggie Thatcher and Helmut Kohl, not by engineers.

Answer (score 3):

> **Why did Eurofighter need collaboration among four countries?**

For production volume.

We are still in an era of relatively low-volume high-value combat aircraft compared to the early years (say pre 1950).

Cost per unit is less if the development costs are spread over a greater number of manufactured units.

Individual European nations each have requirements for relatively small numbers of aircraft. If they each develop and manufacture their own aircraft, costs to each are likely to be higher.

Politically, it is easier to sell a military aircraft to politicians whose countries benefit from the manufacturing.

There are also benefits in sharing development costs.

Given the close economic, political and military ties between European countries, collaboration makes sense.

Comment: For production volume? Are u nuts? as of January 2015, only 427 units were produced. Whereas F-16 was 4500+ built. Sharing dev cost is also not justified in case of F-35.

Comment: @BROY: UK has 160 units. Germany 143, Spain 73, etc. Developing, testing and producing four or five independent designs would be more expensive **per unit**.

Comment: what about US and French fighters?

Comment: Remember, it is also much harder for newly elected politicians to cancel a program if other nations are involved. If the TSR-2 had been an international cooperation ... well, at least after that debacle the British industry finally understood how to get their projects finished.